# Resharper inspectcode fails to find include files

Tags: c++, resharper

Resharper inspectcode fails to find include files in a multi-project Visual Studio 2017 Solution if a specific project is used (e.g. `inspectcode --project=MyProject MySolution.sln -o=MySolution.MyProject.xml`)

I get errors like this:

`<Issue TypeId="CppCompilerErrors" File="MyHeader.h" Offset="1910-1916" Line="41" Message="Cannot find file 'OtherHeader.h' in search paths:&#xD;&#xA;c:\MySolution\MyProject&#xD;&#xA;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include&#xD;&#xA;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include&#xD;&#xA;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt&#xD;&#xA;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\um&#xD;&#xA;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\shared&#xD;&#xA;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\winrt&#xD;&#xA;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt&#xD;&#xA;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\Include\um&#xD;&#xA;" />`

However, there are many more include paths in the `.vcxproj` file, but apparently they aren't being seen.

Surely others have run into this issue.

Comment: It's a big building with a lot of sick error messages in it...

but that doesn't solve my problem.